# Сортировка параграфов (не строк) в Vim

Tags: vim

Предположим, есть следующие строки:

```
2.  Второй параграф.

3.  Третий параграф.

1.  Первый параграф.
```

Хотелось бы получить такой результат:

```
1.  Первый параграф.

2.  Второй параграф.

3.  Третий параграф.
```

Если просто использовать `:sort`, то выйдет:

```
1.  Первый параграф.
2.  Второй параграф.
3.  Третий параграф.
```

То есть, пустые строки сгруппируются перед всеми остальными.  Есть ли в (Neo)Vim'е втроенный способ получить именно сортировку по параграфам?  Или только через плагины или скрипты?